# how to get (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty(“Xrm”) in Silverlight Application when it embedded to HTML Page in CRM

Tags: silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011, guid, dynamics-crm-online

I fetch the Guid of Record using below code in Silverlight Application in CRM.

```
 dynamic xrmnew = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("Xrm");
 Guid Id1 = new Guid(xrmnew.Page.data.entity.getId());
 textBox2.Text = Id1.ToString();
```

Thats fine i got the Guid of Record from Silverlight Application using above code.But if i deploy this Silverlight Page in HTML Page and then try to get Guid of Record using above code then it doesnt able to fetch the Guid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after a lot of hard work i got the answer

```
dynamic xrmnew = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("Xrm");
if (xrmnew == null)
{
    HtmlWindow parentWindow = HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("parent") as HtmlWindow;
    xrmnew = (ScriptObject)parentWindow.GetProperty("Xrm");
}
Guid Id = new Guid(xrmnew.Page.data.entity.getId());
```